# Why do ferries have a trucker's lounge?

Tags: ferries

When on the ferry between Britain and either Netherlands or Ireland, there's a trucker's lounge.  Only truckers allowed.  Why do the ferries have this?  I can understand the point of the Stena Plus Lounge — additional cost for additional luxury — but why the truckers lounge?

Comment: I would say, truckers are a reliable source of income. There is competition and truckers can choose the ferry  company they want to catch. Hence they offer the truckers benefits to get their business.

Comment: @RodneyHawkins I agree, same reason why some hotels have crew lounges.. so airlines would choose them for their crewmembers for overnight layovers...

Comment: @NeanDerThal Interesting, I didn't know about crew lounges.

Comment: Truckers are ferry companies equivalent of airlines Business Class frequent flyers - a good source of regular revenue, if you keep the customer happy....

Comment: Don't forget that the truck is paying a lot more than a regular car.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because **truckers are a solid source of serious revenue**.  If each truck brings in (say) €500 of revenue, and all it takes to get the driver to choose a particular ferry company is a €1 cup of coffee and a spare room with some daggy sofas, offering this as a "trucker's lounge" is a no-brainer.

Incidentally, this kind of thing is pretty common at highway rest areas as well, and long-distance bus drivers in particular know exactly where to go.   Fill up your truck here and get a free cup of coffee, or better yet, drop off a busload of passengers for a break and get a free meal.

Comment: Quite a few highway rest areas come with free showers for truckers as well.

Comment: Or not technically free, but well featured in their membership club programs.